# Decode bits in integer used to store permissions

Tags: sql-server

An existing SQL Server 2014 database stores permissions for users in a 32 bit integer.

```
bit 0 = Read files
bit 1 = Move files
bit 2 = Delete files
bit 3 = Save files
etc.
```

If the bit is 1 the permission is set, if the bit = 0 the permission is not set.

I need a query to show all permissions set for a given user. I have a table that has a list of all 32 permissions and am not sure of how to join the user table with the permissions table to get a list.

For example, if User Joe has permission INT = 3 then the query should return 2 rows:

```
Read Files
Move Files
```

If user Peter has permission INT = 8 then the query should return only 1 row:

```
Save Files
```

If user Dave has permission INT = 7 then the query should return 3 rows:

```
Read files
Move Files
Delete files
```

The permissions table has 3 columns: bit#, value, description

```
0   0   Read Files
1   2   Move Files
2   4   Delete Files
3   8   Save Files
etc.
```

I can easily change the design of the permissions table if different or additional columns would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to store the flags in a table (maybe you already have one):

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.PermissionDefinitions
  (i int, Permission varchar(32));

INSERT dbo.PermissionDefinitions(i, Permission) 
  VALUES 
  (1, 'Read files'),
  (2, 'Move files'),
  (4, 'Delete files'),
  (8, 'Save files'); -- ... more ...
```

And you have a Users table with a column containing their permission set:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Users(Username sysname, PermissionSet int);

INSERT dbo.Users VALUES(N'Joe', 3), (N'Suzy', 15);
```

Then you can just `cross join` all those with `bitwise and`:

```
SELECT u.Username, ps.Permission 
  FROM dbo.Users AS u
  CROSS JOIN dbo.PermissionDefinitions AS ps
  WHERE u.PermissionSet & ps.i = ps.i;
```

[Example fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/CqOP04bB).

You can also use `INNER JOIN`, same results, same plan, etc.

```
SELECT u.Username, ps.Permission 
  FROM dbo.Users AS u
  INNER JOIN dbo.PermissionDefinitions AS ps
  ON u.PermissionSet & ps.i = ps.i;
```

Comment: The cross join works but the values rather than bit number need to be used. So, 
INSERT dbo.PermissionDefinitions(i, Permission) VALUES 
  (1, 'Read files'),
  (2, 'Move files'),
  (4, 'Delete files'),
  (8, 'Save files'),
  ; -- ... more ...

Comment: Why `CROSS JOIN ... WHERE` rather than a more usual `JOIN ... ON.`

Comment: @Charlieface [Dealer's choice](https://dbfiddle.uk/_5tzkY_Q)?

Comment: I didn't say it would be more efficient (it quite obviously amounts to the same relational algebra so makes no difference to the optimizer). It's just more usual to do an inner join rather than a cross join + filter.